# .NET GDI+ image size - file codec limitations

Tags: .net, gdi+, codec

Is there a limit on the size of image that can be encoded using the image file codecs available from .NET?

I'm trying to encode images > 4GB in size, but it simply does not work (or does not work properly i.e. writes out an unreadable file) with .bmp, .jpg, .png or the .tif encoders.

When I lower the image size to < 2GB it does work with the .jpg but not the .bmp, .tif or .png.

My next attempt would be to try libtiff because I know tiff files are meant for large images.

What is a good file format for large images? or am I just hitting the file format limitations?

(All of this is being done on a 64 bit operating system (WinXP 64) w/ 8 GB of RAM and compiled using x64 architecture.)

```
Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

int width = 64000;
int height = 64000;
int stride = (width % 4) > 0 ? width + (width % 4) : width;
UIntPtr dataSize = new UIntPtr((ulong)stride * (ulong)height);
IntPtr p = Program.VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, dataSize, Program.AllocationType.COMMIT | Program.AllocationType.RESERVE, Program.MemoryProtection.READWRITE);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, p);
BitmapData bd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

ColorPalette cp = bmp.Palette;
for (int i = 0; i < cp.Entries.Length; i++)
{
  cp.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
}
bmp.Palette = cp;

unsafe
{
  for (int y = 0; y < bd.Height; y++)
  {
    byte* row = (byte*)bd.Scan0.ToPointer() + (y * bd.Stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < bd.Width; x++)
    {
      *(row + x) = (byte)r.Next(256);
    }
  }
}

bmp.UnlockBits(bd);
bmp.Save(@"c:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmp.Dispose();

Program.VirtualFree(p, UIntPtr.Zero, 0x8000);
```

I have also tried using a pinned GC memory region, but this is limited to < 2GB.

```
Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

int bytesPerPixel = 4;
int width = 4000;
int height = 4000;         
int padding = 4 - ((width * bytesPerPixel) % 4);
padding = (padding == 4 ? 0 : padding);
int stride = (width * bytesPerPixel) + padding;
UInt32[] pixels = new UInt32[width * height];
GCHandle gchPixels = GCHandle.Alloc(pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, gchPixels.AddrOfPinnedObject()))
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        int row = (y * width);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            pixels[row + x] = (uint)r.Next();
        }
    }

    bmp.Save(@"c:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
gchPixels.Free();
```

Comment: What processor architecture are you using?

Comment: @Rowland - Compiled using x64. So 64 bit. I don't think 32 bit would suffice for such large images. My machine has 8GB of RAM, perhaps that's not enough though it should be for an image slightly over 4GB.  I have about 7GB free, when the encoder kicks in there is still about 1-2GB free.

Comment: @roygbiv Just checking the obvious :)

Comment: BMP is limited to expressing image dimensions with 2 signed 16-bit integers, so assuming 32 BPP, the largest BMP can't be 4GB (32767*32767*4 bytes for the image data).

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is very likely the following limitation in the .NET Framework: the  maximum object size allowed in the GC Heap is 2GB, even on 64-bit OS / builds.

Some references: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160819180509/https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=592), [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160820005203/https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=659), [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217070908/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx).

Depending on your needs, with a relatively simple (uncompressed) format like TIFF it *might* be doable to generate your image in parts and merge the parts afterwards. Just an idea..

Comment: As I point out, I can use VirtualAlloc to create in memory bitmaps > 4GB, however, the various encoders fail to write such images to disk. If you are suggesting that the encoder itself requires > 2GB of RAM then I don't think that's a very efficient encoder.

Comment: I skimmed through the code fast, but you should test if Bitmap.Save tries to construct the image in memory (again) before writing it to the filestream (maybe it does). That would explain the behaviour...

Comment: I will step through it again, but it appears that it does not reconstruct the image before saving it.

Answer (score 1):

From the TIFF specification Section 2: TIFF Structure at at http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf:

> TIFF is an image file format. In this
>   document, a file is defined to be a
>   sequence of 8-bit bytes, where the
>   bytes are numbered from 0 to N. The
>   largest possible TIFF file is 2**32
>   bytes in length.

Unfortunately many TIFF writers and readers use signed integers in implementation and reduce the practical size to 2**31. This is compounded by the frequent attempt by drivers to keep the entire image in memory as mentioned by Cristophe.

You are likely to find similar limitations in the other image formats created in the '80s or earlier. Multi gigabyte file size limits were not considered a problem when disks were only in the tens of megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

So your goal is to encode them into jpeg?  I am sure there would be a way to pull in only the section you are encoding, then dispose and go on to the next section.  If you open the file raw and and parse it yourself, I am sure there are open source jpeg encoders out there to help with creating the sections.  This should allow you to encode files extremely large, but your will always have OS and filesystem hurdles to overcome.