# using Gdiplus Graphics::DrawImage crashes on large images

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

How can I use Gdiplus to render an image 24000 x 48000 with 32-bit pixel depth?  On my machine I have 32GB RAM.  Or alternatively, how can I use GDIplus to scale a bitmap without drawing it into another bitmap?  I'm writing a simulation and some get that large.  HELP!

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit build target?  A 32-bit build only has a 2 GB per process address space, or 3 GB if /largeaddressaware flag is set.

Comment: It's GDI+ see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175585/what-is-the-maximum-resolution-of-c-sharp-net-bitmap (Hans Passant's answer)

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT not really a helpful comment. It's pretty clear from the question that they *do* have enough memory to hold the image. Dave S comment has the real answer.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I especially appreciate Dave S for his answer.  I am coding in C++/Win API, not C#/.NET.  If WIC is available there, then that is my next answer

Comment: @user9778277 emmm, I'm sorry to provide you with a link to. net, so did your problem be solved according to the method provided by Dave S?

Comment: Yes.  There is no time to which to WIC, but I will put it on the Task list for next release.