# Totally stumpted - System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I've written a quick winform app that can take some entered text, generate images based on all the system fonts and then consolidate those images into a single image to give examples of the fonts. For ease, I've separated the two functions, one to generate the images and another to consolidate them so I can remove fonts I don't want in the single image. It was all working yesterday, but now when it comes to saving the consolidated image ("complete.save("consolidated.png");) it gives the useless GDI+ error. I've checked paths and access, all are fine and correct. Nothing is locking the image, so I'm totally at a loss as what is causing this. Any ideas? Code below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        List<string> files = FileSystemUtilities.ListFiles("fonts");

        int height = 0;
        int width = 0;

        Bitmap test = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
        Graphics gTest = Graphics.FromImage(test);

        Font font = new Font("Arial", 128);

        int numWidth = 0;

        int count = 1;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}\r", FileSystemUtilities.GetFileName(file).Replace(".png", string.Empty));

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);

            height = height + bitmap.Height + 10;

            if (width < bitmap.Width)
            {
                width = bitmap.Width;
            }

            SizeF numSize = gTest.MeasureString(Convert.ToString(count), font);

            if (numWidth < numSize.Width)
            {
                numWidth = Convert.ToInt32(numSize.Width + 1);
            }

            bitmap.Dispose();

            count++;
        }

        test.Dispose();
        gTest.Dispose();

        numWidth = numWidth + 10;
        count = 1;
        Bitmap complete = new Bitmap(width + numWidth, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(complete);

        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, complete.Width, complete.Height);

        int y = 0;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);

            g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(count) + ".", font, Brushes.Black, 0, y);

            g.DrawImage(bitmap, numWidth, y);

            y = y + bitmap.Height + 10;

            bitmap.Dispose();

            count++;
        }

        string filename = "consolidated.png";

        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            File.Delete(filename);
        }

        g.Dispose();
        complete.Save("consolidated.png");
        complete.Dispose();

        TextFileUtilities.WriteTextFile("consolidated.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: What line does it throw an exception on? Did you step through with a debugger?

Comment: Which versions of .NET/C#/Windows are you running this on?

Comment: Should have said that, will edit... throws on complete.Save("filename"); and yes I have, no idea what is causing it as no info given other than GDI+ error

Comment: If you have no files, your height is zero.  You should check for that.

Comment: checked that, not issue.

Comment: .NET is version 4.6.1

Comment: The image it is trying to save is 647 wide by 75468 high

Comment: You're probably running into GDI+ limitations at that size.   See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175585/what-is-the-maximum-resolution-of-c-sharp-net-bitmap) for more details...

Comment: [What is the maximum resolution of C# .NET Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176435/7444103)

Comment: Ok I'll try removing some of the font images and make it smaller, therefore making it within the supposed limits.

Comment: Btw, the description of what this process is for doesn't match the code's ops.

Comment: I didn't post the entire code because it wasn't necessary. The error lay within this part of the code only (it's in it's own method and separate from the other image creation code)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to excessive height... I couldn't see it. Thank you for all that commented and helped me out.

Comment: Glad you have a solution.  Be sure to upvote one or more of the answers in the linked question.