# Increasing height of WebBrowser using asp.net c# code then getting error: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webbrowser-control

Increasing height of `WebBrowser` using asp.net c# code then getting error:

`Parameter is not valid.`

below is my code for taking screenshot of the page

```
    private void webbrowse_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webrowse = sender as WebBrowser;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webrowse.Width, webrowse.Height);
        webrowse.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, webrowse.Bounds); //geting error in this line

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] strbytes = stream.ToArray();
        imgscreenshot.Visible = true;
        imgscreenshot.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(strbytes);    

    }
```

if I will increase the height of `webrowser.Height = 20000;` in above `GenerateThumbnail` method then getting error :`Parameter is not valid.` I have 20 pages height in my aspx page thats why want to increase the height. I am not able to increase long size height.

Comment: bro if 5000 height value then output coming, but if i will increase the height from 5000 to 20000 height then getting error. @JesúsNarváezTamés

Comment: Take a look to this thread. They speak about the memory restrictions for bitmaps.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175585/what-is-the-maximum-resolution-of-c-sharp-net-bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for a while with @Mohd Mazhar Khan there is a solution:

> The iss express was in 32-bit and it should be configured  in 64-bit for manage
>   big amounts of memory.

For changing the settings is this way:

> Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>Web Project and check the 64-bit
>   IISEXPRESS box.

Comment: Please share answer output code. @Jesús Narváez Tamés

Comment: I have added : Bitmap b = new Bitmap(65535,65535, PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed); getting same error bro. @Jesús Narváez Tamés

Comment: Have you tried this way ? Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webrowse.Width, webrowse.Height, PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed);

Comment: 64 bits. this also givin same error: Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webrowse.Width, webrowse.Height, PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed); .@Jesús Narváez Tamés

Comment: sorry i did not understand, what you are asking?.@Jesús Narváez Tamés

Comment: Try by adding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element this flag (from link) into your configuration file :)

Comment: I have already added this code: 
    <runtime>
      <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime> in my web config.

Comment: Hmm... Then, How many RAM memory do you have available when you run the application ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197680/discussion-between-mohd-mazhar-khan-and-jesus-narvaez-tames).